# What are the differences between implementing HTTPS everywhere via IIS or MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis

I'm working on a project to require HTTPS everywhere among a suite of MVC and WebAPI applications. I'm trying to understand the trade-offs between clicking the "Require SSL" checkbox in IIS & using a URL Rewrite zmodule vs. using a RequireHttpsAttribute in my global filters and modifying my web.config.

I've found the following guides detailing each approach:

https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/28057/iis-7-require-ssl-automatically-redirect-to-https
http://tech.trailmax.info/2014/02/implemnting-https-everywhere-in-asp-net-mvc-application/

[image: Require SSL IIS option]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Explain the mechanism can be lengthy, so I will just list the most significant differences in behaviour:

1. do "Require SSL" in IIS:
   The context basically expalin what it do, it's "Require" not "Enforce", which means, if people trying to access your website content through http, the server will just respond with a 403 error, which is usually not a desired behavior, but this may help some certain situation
2. using URL rewrite module:
   The module itself can do quite some different thing, but I assume you are just going to do the regular https redirect. Which means, if user trying to hit ANY content of the site through http, the server will do a 301 or 302 redirect to the https version of same url. This is usually a good option since it doesn't affect any usability of the website.
3. Global `RequireHttpsAttribute` action filter: This do similar thing to option number 2, it will do a 302 redirect for any http request that is hitting an ACTION. The main difference is that this only applies to all actions in your controllers, Which means, if someone trying to just get a image or css file through http on your website, this option will let it through and not do any enforcement. This leave you the capability to serve static contents through http, which can be useful in some specific circumstances

Just one extra thing worth mention, the 301 and 302 redirect is not going too well with http POST, so if your user trying to do a post through http, the request body will get lost (thanks to the info from @ChrisPratt).

Comment: If you send a POST over HTTP when all requests to HTTP are redirected to HTTPS, the post body will be dropped. You won't necessarily get an error, assuming that the endpoint can also respond to GET. However, it's typical to disallow direct POST requests to prevent CSRF, anyways, so it shouldn't really be a problem.

Comment: @ChrisPratt I never really did any experiment on doing redirect on POST. Thanks for the info, I will update the answer.

Comment: Just to clarify what's happening actually: Redirects are actually a response. Instead of a 200 response code with an HTML document payload, the client gets a 301 or 302 with a payload that consists of just a URL - the URL the server suggests you go to instead. The client, typically a web browser, then issues another request to that new URL. The reason POST doesn't work here is that the client will get that redirect response, and then fetch the redirect URL via *GET* as is typical. It's not so much that the post body is lost as just never used.

Answer (score 0):

Typically the folks managing the infrastructure are responsible for making sure things are on https. Typically they aren't very good at this so that is where the RequireHttpsAttribute kicks in as it can encforce https requests at a code level thereby enforcing the HTTPS-only attribute.

In practice it isn't so great as many production setups -- including stackoverflow.com's -- see https terminated in an edge device before being unwrapped and handed to the back-end apps as http and the require https attribute isn't quite nuanced enough to understand this distinction.

The best bet in general is to configure the edge device providing the public http interface to take HTTPS and only HTTPS. Then setup secondary virtual sites [or whatever is vendor appropriate] to redirect all traffic to the cannonical HTTPS url. I'd be a bit nervous about relying upon the RequireHttpsAttribute unless it will be a small app handling it's own requests. That still leaves open holes in terms of artifacts and other things that might not be coming off of a controller.